# openai command not found (mac)

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-api

I'm trying to follow the fine tuning guide for Openai [here](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning).

I ran:

```
pip install --upgrade openai
```

Which install without any errors.

But even after restarting my terminal, i still get

```
zsh: command not found: openai
```

Here is the output of echo $PATH:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nickrose/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Here is the output of which python:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Any tips for how to fix this? I'm on MacOS Big Sur 11.6.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to run `openai` from the *shell*, and why should it work? This is a Python package, it is *not* meant to be run from the shell!

Comment: According to the doc, you should be able to use OpenAI's CLI tool: https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

I understand I can also do this using the Python package, I'm just curious why the CLI doesn't work.

Comment: Here's a quick guide on how to set up the OpenAI CLI on Mac: https://kevingoedecke.com/2023/04/14/how-to-install-openai-cli-on-macos/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically pip installs the packages under its related python directory, in a directory called `site-packages` (most likely, I'm not a python expert tbh). This is not included in the path you provided. First, ask pip to show the location to the package:

```bash
pip show openai
```

The output would be something like this:

```
Name: openai
Version: 0.22.0
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License: 
Location: /Users/<USER>/DIR/TO/SOME/PYTHON/site-packages
Requires: numpy, openpyxl, pandas, pandas-stubs, requests, tqdm
Required-by:
```

So your package will be available in

```bash
/Users/<USER>/DIR/TO/SOME/PYTHON/site-packages/openai
```

Either add `/Users/<USER>/DIR/TO/SOME/PYTHON/site-packages/` to your path, or use the complete address to your package, or try to access it using your python:

```bash
python -m openai # -m stands for module
```

To get more information about the `-m` flag, run `python --help`.

### Update

So as you mentioned in the comments, you get `permission denied` after you add the directory to your package. This actually means that the package exists, but it's not permitted by your OS to execute. This is the thing you have to do, locate your package, and then:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /PATH/TO/script
```

And the reason you're getting `command not found` after you use sudo directly with the package, is that you update your path variable in `zsh`, but when you use `sudo`, superuser uses `sh` instead of `zsh`.

Comment: I tried this but got the following:
python3 -m openai:

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: No module named openai.__main__; 'openai' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: Does your pip use `python3`? it's more likely you should use `python -m openai` instead of `python3 -m openai`. Or, you can do this: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade openai`, and then: `python3 -m openai`.

Comment: I also tried adding that Location to my PATH variable (i used pip show openai first), and then tried running openai, but I get a 
zsh: permission denied: openai

Then i tried sudo openai, enter my password correctly, and then I get command not found

Comment: Thanks for the update! I now tried the chmod command, but I still get the "command not found" error after using sudo directly with the package. How do i actually update my PATH variable in sh, rather than in zsh?

Comment: `but I still get the "command not found" error after using sudo directly with the package`, you should not use sudo with the package, you should use `sudo chmod +x package` (If I understood your question correctly). Updating your sh Path is not a good idea in general, but if you couldn't make it with `chmod`, you can update your profile, or sh resource file if exists.

Comment: Tried that as well -- sudo chmod +x /Users/nickrose/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openai api fine_tunes
.create -t fine_tune.jsonl -m davinci

(this command is meant to do this part of the tutorial: openai api fine_tunes.create -t <TRAIN_FILE_ID_OR_PATH> -m <BASE_MODEL>). 

But now I get a bunch of "no such file or directory" errors from chmod for 'api', 'fine_tunes.create', and all the arguments that come after the path/to/openai part

Comment: @Nick, the `chmod` command changes the permissions of a script/application. So you'll first need to tell your OS to change the mode of the file to `executable` (by `-x` flag) like this: `sudo chmod +x Users/nickrose/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openai` (no trailing arguments), and then, execute the app normally (`openai api fine_tunes .create -t fine_tune.jsonl -m davinci`)

Comment: @Nick @AminMal So I am stuck in the same issue I tried the same things. I ran the command `sudo chmod +x /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai` and ran the command for openai but still got `zsh: command not found: openai`

Comment: @Nick The "command not found" error is due to ".../site-packages/openai" is a directory... and not an executable. Hence "chmod +x" won't help it, nor does sudo. The openai package. The binary "openai" is located in a different directory for my computer it's `/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.9/bin/openai` ; hence you would need to add `/Users/<your-user-name>/Library/Python/<Python-Version>/bin` to your path or call it using the full path.

Comment: What should be the variable name while adding the path? @AminMal

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal there’s no need for a new variable, you basically just append a new path to already-existing path.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing similar issue. It might due to global python in your machine is  not maching with the pip installation path and it might be installing in some other python folder like in 3.9 and you have 3.10 python version globally set in your Mac.

First install fresh python using homebrew

```
brew install python
```

It will install the latest python into your machine. Then try to install openai again using

```
pip3 install openai
```

OR using pip (you can try installing using both and see which works as per your system config)

```
pip install openai
```

Now

```
ENJOY a cup of coffee ;)
```

Answer (score 3):

***This doesn't answer the question directly but specifies an alternative if you only want to prepare the data set and create the new model for finetunning. It doesn't matter which system you have.***

After a lot of struggle I decided it was not worth the hassel to run the cli on my specific machine because of so many different configurations and the mess. My end goal was just to create a model and upload it to OpenAI.

So if someone else stumbles on this post, just use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). I have also shared one of mine with steps to follow in [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ty3ZbA8aMvCo_qnlEdeJEEViDasX82SA?usp=sharing).

In case the links don't work in the future I'll list the steps here below as well:

**(Step 1)**

Set your API key (The already added api key is fake so please replace it with your own):

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY=sk-Kz8Weh1234ddgYBmsdfinsdf7ndsfg55532432
```

**(Step 2)**

Install the openai package with pip like the following:

```
!pip install -Uq openai
```

**(Step 3)**

Import the openai package like the following:

```
import openai
```

**(Step 4)**

Make sure to upload the *promptdata.csv* file in the Google Colab folders.

The way to do it is:

1. On the right side you'll see a Hamburger Menu icon click on it.
2. You'll see the "Table of Contents"
3. Click on the last folder icon on the top. If you hover on the icon it says "Files".
4. Now you'll see a folder called "sample_data".
5. Click on the three dots menu for "sample_data" and then select "upload".
6. You should be able to upload your csv file
7. It is not mandatory to upload a csv file. You can also upload any type of TSV, XLSX, JSON or JSONL file as listed by the OpenAI documentation here. But it will always be converted to JSONL file after runnning the below command.

Once you're done uploading the file you can run the below command to prepare your data set which will return you a new JSONL file at the same location where the original file was with all the corrections the tool provides.

```
!openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f "/content/sample_data/promptdata.csv"
```

**(Step 5)**

Run the below command once again after the corrections and it will most likely say "No remediations found".

```
!openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f "/content/sample_data/promptdata_prepared.jsonl"
```

**(Step 6)**

Finally run the below command using the file *promptdata_prepared.jsonl* and create a model.

```
!openai api fine_tunes.create -t "/content/sample_data/promptdata_prepared.jsonl"
```

**(Step 7)**

Once the model is created note the name of the "Uploaded model"

Answer (score 2):

So what happens is that after installing the package there are no actual executables available. That's why you get the error message when you try to execute for example:

```
openai --help
```

What i managed to find is that the actual parsing of the commands is done in

```
/Users/<USER>/DIR_TO_PYTHON/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py
```

That's just a python script which by default is not executable, so you have to make a workaround of which I find the easiest is creating an executable which basically calls it with the given arguments. Below are the steps which I've done to make it work on "macOS Monterey 12.0.1"

Locate the "openai" package which should be in

```
/Users/<USER>/DIR_TO_PYTHON/site-packages/
```

Make sure you are in the "openai" package folder and run

```
sudo vim /bin/openai
```

That should create a new file, put in the following command and make sure the path to the file is correct

```
python3 /Users/<USER>/DIR_TO_PYTHON/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py $@
```

`$@` is for the params that you pass when you call the executable

After saving the file the next step is making it executable which is done with

```
chmod +x /bin/openai
```

Last step is adding it to the PATH which is done by adding the file path in `/etc/paths` and after restarting the terminal, you should have fully working `openai` command globally

Comment: Tried `sudo vim /bin/openai` and entered `python3 /Users/<USER>/DIR_TO_PYTHON/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py $@` but now can't exit vim after trying `:wq` What should I do?

Comment: Can you send the error? Otherwise It would be a wild guess.

Comment: I found out that I did not have some access rights on my work laptop. I don't think I solved the issue but used Google Colab to fine tune eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error, but after some searching, I successfully installed it with `brew`

`brew install openai`

[image: install openai]

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

I created an executable in  `/usr/local/bin` that executes the OpenAI Python script:

> `~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py`

Here's the command I used:

```
 sudo sh -c 'echo python3 /home/<MY_USERNAME>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/_openai_scripts.py \$\@ > /usr/local/bin/openai'
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several other suggestions which didn't work for me on my Mac, I consulted my son who is a python developer.  He suggested creating a python virtual environment on my Mac (MacOS: Ventura, 13.4; Chip: M1 Pro) as follows:

`python3 -m venv openaiwork` (this will create a new openaiwork virtual directory in the current location)

```
source openaiwork/bin/activate

pip install openai
```

I also needed to install pandas in this new virtual environment using:

```
pip install pandas
```

Once set up as described above, the openai scripts worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you meet:

```
WARNING: The script openai.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\...\...\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
```

You should:

```
export PATH="~\...\...\local-packages\Python39\Scripts:$PATH"
```

For MacOS and Linux：

```
export PATH="/path/to/scripts:$PATH"
```

For Windows：

```
setx /m PATH "%PATH%;C:\path\to\scripts"
```

Replace C:\path\to\scripts with path to scripts

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for Python3

Run the following command to install the OpenAI CLI

```
pip3 install --upgrade openai
```

If you now run `openai --help` you will still get an error message, telling you command not found.

The next step is to make the Python OpenAI script executable and add it to our path.

Make the OpenAI CLI executable
We will have to create a binary file in your local users bin directory (/usr/local/bin). This directory contains all executable binaries that are specific to your user.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo python3 "$(python3 -m site --user-site)"/openai/_openai_scripts.py \$\@ > /usr/local/bin/openai'
```

What this command does is the following:

- We get the path to the python site packages directory where all global python packages are installed to: `python3 -m site --user-site` .
- We extend that path to map to the OpenAI CLI scripts Python script: `openai/_openai_scripts.py`.
- We then pipe this into a file in the `/usr/local/bin` directory to use it from anywhere as a shell command.

The last thing we need to do now is to make that file executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/openai
```

This should be it, you should now be able to run the OpenAI CLI from anywhere in your terminal.

You can test this by doing the following:

```
openai --help
```

Which should return all available OpenAI CLI commands.

Thanks to this [blog](https://kevingoedecke.com/2023/04/14/how-to-install-openai-cli-on-macos/)