# zsh: permission denied (MacOS)

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I am trying to use a tool from Openai (train a data model).

I installed openai and now try to execute this command:

```
/Users/finnborchers/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f /Users/finnborchers/Desktop/Code/GPT3_Training_data/training.jsonl
```

I get this error:

```
zsh: permission denied: /Users/finnborchers/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openai
```

I had the same problem from this article, but now I am stuck:

[openai command not found (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73186315/openai-command-not-found-mac)

I am new to the terminal commands, but here is the output of echo $PATH:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/finnborchers/Flutter_api/flutter/bin
```

To allow execution I tried this command:

```
sudo chmod +x /Users/finnborchers/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/openai
```

But then nothing happens (There is no feedback message) and I still get the permission denied message.
Maybe the chmod did not work because of the PATH?

I am thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to run the first installation with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a executable script in `/usr/local/bin`.

To do so run the following command:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo python3 "$(python3 -m site --user-site)"/openai/_openai_scripts.py \$\@ > /usr/local/bin/openai'
```

Then make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/openai
```

Now you don't always have to specify the path to the python script, you can simply run `openai --help` from anywhere.