# zsh: command not found: openai (on WSL)

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zshrc, openai-api

I was trying to install openai to fine tune the model and use opeanAI cli to train the model.

```
python --version
```

**Python 3.10.6**

I also installed openai package

```
pip show openai

Name: openai
Version: 0.26.4
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License:
Location: /home/vanshmittal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, requests, tqdm
Required-by:
```

**.zshrc** file contains

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3.10
export PATH="$PATH:/home/vanshmittal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai"
```

On checking $PATH

```
 echo $PATH

it had the above path provided
:/home/vanshmittal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai
```

on running **opeanAI CLI** command says **zsh: command not found: openai**

```
openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f <file_path>
```

I also followed this stackoverflow question:- [openai command not found (mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73186315/openai-command-not-found-mac)

```
python -m openai
/usr/bin/python3: No module named openai.__main__; 'openai' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Made the file executable also

```
sudo chmod +x /home/vanshmittal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/
```

But even after that also it's returning **zsh: command not found: openai**
Could anyone please help me, what additionally needs to be done for successfull installation?

Comment: You should have `/home/vanshmittal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/` in your `PATH` without adding `openai`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg tried thanks for the response but it's also showing zsh:command not found

Comment: Can you verify that the directory is in your PATH? Try `echo $PATH`. If it's not there, run `source ~/.zshrc` and try again.

Comment: @Rahul ```echo $path``` already has openai package path

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error after trying several times, I solved it by adding the following to my zshrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/USER/.local/bin

export PATH="$PATH:/home/USER/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai"
```

I hope I can solve your problem

Comment: The second line is useless, there's no executables installed into "site-packages" dir

Comment: This worked for me on win 10, wsl2, python3.9

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making an executable bash script in `/usr/loca/bin/`.

Execute the following command to create a bash script that calls the the OpenAI Python CLI script:

```bash
sudo sh -c 'echo python3 "$(python3 -m site --user-site)"/openai/_openai_scripts.py \$\@ > /usr/local/bin/openai'
```

and then make that script executable:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/openai
```

Afterwards you should be able to simply execute `openai --help` or any other openai cli command from your shell/terminal.